# Can I rewire a 240 V 3 phase steamer to a 240 V 1-2 phase?

Tags: three-phase, conversion, phase, phase-shift, single-phase

I have this steamer unit that came in as 240 V, 3 phase that I am trying to adapt to a 1 (2) phase household. The unit needs 60 A and generate 9 kW.

As per the manufacturer, and the below diagrams, I need to switch the wires from figure 12 to figure 11.

I am trying to have a confirmation from experts if this actually makes sense.

[image: 3 phases figure 12]

[image: 2 phases figure 11]

Comment: Ask the manufacturer of the equipment. And your chances of getting a answer is increasing significantly if you add a url/model +++ to the equipment.

Comment: EEK 60A three phase and you want to run it on household service....

Comment: Can you, maybe, should you, probably not. There is also no guarantee that the parts shown in each schematic are the same. Even wiring weights may differ. Further, if you get it wrong, that's a lot of power you are playing with.... **"There be dragons here!"**

Comment: Tks. I added the detailed diagrams and the model is not easy to find online. It is TOLO 90 steamtec AIO.
I need to understand if it is possible to rewire the unit from one diagram 3 phases to the other one 1-2 phase.

Comment: In my country is not possible to get a contract for 60A on a single phase for household, don't know if in your country can either.

Comment: @Trevor except it's really 21A 3-phase if the 9kva is to be believed.  37.5A single phase, not even as big as a range.

Comment: @Harper yes but I'd be expecting much larger in-rush on that thing.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it looks reasonable.  It was originally wired for 240V 3-phase "delta", with 2 separate banks of contactors hooking up heaters 123 or 456,  and all that fed through the 3-channel overheat protector.

The new wiring is for USA style single phase: Both contactors (all 3 poles each) switch phase  L1 in parallel, connecting heaters 123 and/or 456, and current returns via the 3-channel overheat protector (paralleled) to phase L2.

Obviously the machine was built with both these configurations in mind.

With the new wiring, it would work on US style 240V split-phase.  It would also work in theory on EU style 230V single-phase.

However as a practical thing that would probably not happen because EU power companies wouldn't want you drawing that much from one phase, They actually bring 400V 3-phase "wye" (230V to neutral) right to the pole in front of your house, and would bring 2-3 phases to a well equipped house.  This "wye" configuration would be yet a third diagram.

But I doubt it's in Europe.  240V "delta" is silly when houses get 400V wye.

I agree 9kw equals slightly under 40 amps, which in standard installation practice in North America would require a 50A circuit (6 AWG wire, good for 60A based on NEC 310.16 tables, I would still use a 50A breaker).   If you could meet all the criteria for 100% factoring, you could snake it onto a 40A/8 AWG circuit.

Answer (score 0):

240 V is equal to the EU/UK model. It needs **40 Amps** for 9 kW, on **1 phase**.
That's a lot of current. It would need 16mm2 (4/5 AWG) wiring.
*I doubt that is needs 60 Amps, as you've stated*

If you have looked at the schematics in detail, you would have seen you would have to rewire basically everything.

The 3-Phase model has: terminal -> protection -> relays -> heaters.
The 1-Phase model has: terminal -> relays -> heaters -> protection.
The heaters are also configured differently.

Could you? Yes sure, if you think it's worth it. *(note: wire is expensive)*
Should you? No. It will impact warranty and safety.

Before you go and buy the correct one. What is the rating on your **main fuse**?